# End examples with padding and a little mark

Tags: formatting, environments

What I want to do can be illustrated with this picture:

---

[image]

---

I want the examples to be numbered, draw two slashes after every example and add a little vertical spacing between the end of the examples and the next paragraph.

I tried with the following code, two different ways but with one I get the numbering but don't know how to get the lines and with the other I don't know how to get the numbering.

---

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    openright,%
    parskip=full,
    spanish,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newenvironment{ExampleOne}
  {\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$ / / $}\begin{proof}[Ejemplo]}
    {\end{proof}}
\newtheorem{ExampleTwo}[theorem]{Ejemplo}


\begin{document}
\begin{ExampleOne}
    This is an example
\end{ExampleOne}

\begin{ExampleTwo}
    This is a second example
\end{ExampleTwo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what notation and numbering you really want, but the following example is easy to modify:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    openright,%
    parskip=full,
    spanish,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newenvironment{ExampleOne}
  {\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$ / / $}\begin{proof}[Ejemplo]}
    {\end{proof}}   
    
 \newtheorem{ExampleTwo}[theorem]{Ejemplo}   

\newenvironment{mythm}{\begin{ExampleTwo}}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$ / / $}\qed \end{ExampleTwo}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Uno}

Yours:

\begin{ExampleOne}
    This is an example
\end{ExampleOne}

\begin{ExampleTwo}
    This is a second example
\end{ExampleTwo}

The new one:

\begin{mythm}
This is the third example
\end{mythm}


\end{document}
```

[image]